# How to check for the user session and re-create one on the fly on each page?

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, web-config

I have a web app written with ASP on an IIS server.

Sometimes, after logging in automatically (with LDAP authentication), and after being idle for some minutes, users go to a page where they want to edit something, and the server shows an error saung that they don't have a permission or the session is timed out as follows:
[image: error page note]

I want Kinda like a decorator on each page that would assign the user a new session if it doesn’t exist.

I believe it's something that should be done in IIS, like webconfig.

Any help would be really appreciated!!
Thanks!!

IIS Advanced Setting page:
[image: IIS Advanced Settings]

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below things:

1)Set ideal time out for application pool:

- On the left side, select"Application Pools".
- On the right side, right-click your site application pool from the list. application pool and select Advanced Settings
- In the advanced settings, increase "Idle Time-out (minutes)".

2)Connection timeout setting:

- Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
- Expand the local computer node, expand Web Sites, right-click the appropriate Web site, point to Manage Web Site, click Advanced Settings.
- In the Advanced Settings window, expand Connection Limits, change the value in the Connection time-out field, and then click OK.

3)Active Server Pages (ASP) setting:

- Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
- Expand the local computer node, expand Web Sites, select the appropriate website, and double-click Session State in the right-hand panel.
- Change the setting for Time-Out.

4)ASP Script Timeout Settings:

- Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
- Expand the local computer node, expand Web Sites, select the appropriate website, and double-click ASP in the right-hand panel.
- In the ASP window, expand 'Limits Properties' and change the Script Timeout value.

Set HTTP keep-alive enable in iis.

Comment: Thanks @Jalpa, I tried all of them and will see if it happens again (will get back to you with the result)! However, I can't do step #3, as I don't see the Session State (I assigned a picture of the IIS setting at the end of my post above to let you see what I have), which one is it?

Comment: @Mikael for that you have to install the asp.net feature. check this [image](https://imgur.com/a/nGntVkd)

Comment: @Mikael which kind of application you are using?